# executing runtime cmd from java program

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I want to run my Ant script i.e (build.xml) through my java program , following is part of mycode

```
  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process proc = rt.exec("build.xml");
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "build.xml": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
    at com.infotech.RunCmd.main(RunCmd.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 4 more
```

How to solve it?

Comment: I think you are missing a few commands inside your rt.exec(..).  Perhaps it should read rt.exec("ant [target]").  As it stands you are trying to execute an xml file.

Comment: shouldn't be you trying something `Process proc = rt.exec("PATH/TO/ANT_HOME/ant [options] [target [target2 [target3] ...]]");`

Comment: If you are still having issues could you add to this question, otherwise could you please accept an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should execute `ant -buildfile build.xml`, so use `rt.exec("ant -buildfile build.xml");` (**build.xml** is not a command) if build.xml is not in the application folder, you will need to give its actual path.

Answer (score 0):

Is build.xml actually in the directory you are running from, have you tried putting the file directory path in rt.exec()?

Answer (score 0):

You do not invoke "build.xml" from command line, but "ant" that looks for a "build.xml" in your current directory. So change your code (assuming ant launcher is accessible from your PATH) to:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("ant");
```

Comment: here is my actual code , still iam getting error.Actally my build.xml which i want to run is in following path D:ant\trai; my Ant_Home is in D:apacheant\bin

Answer (score 0):

For a start, the *executable* is `ant`. The *command parameter* is `build.xml`.

Secondly, you need to use absolute paths for your files/executables or be sure of your runtime environment's directory